# Tombstones and key store cleanup

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a few Kafka consumers implemented in Java and I am implementing a standalone application to check records and tombstone them. The hope is that Kafka will delete state stores as it compacts topics.

Now... I am getting a bit confused on the different types of stores that are created by Kafka. For each type of store, I would like to know:

- Is it deleted when Kafka deletes old records in the corresponding topic?
- Is it deleted when you tombstone records in the corresponding topic?
- Are we stuck with it?

The types of stores that I see are the following:

1. KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE changelog
2. KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE repartition
3. (KTABLE) STATE-STORE changelog
4. KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT repartition

For the stream topology using an Aggregate function, we already have a tombstone strategy which should cover stores of type #1. We send a null message to the stream application & it returns it as the aggregate result.

For stores of type #3, I will be running a tombstoning application on the corresponding ktable. I expect the changelog to shrink.

However, for stores of type #2 and #4, I have no idea how they are cleaned up. They corresponding to selectKey()+leftJoin() functions in my consumer's topology. However, they are tied to a kstream-centric topology so I don't know what to do to have them cleaned up. Any suggestions that don't involve stopping the broker?

Comment: `We send a null message to the stream application & it returns it as the aggregate result.` -- I would assume this does not work because `null`-value records are not processed by a `KStream` aggregation operator -- you would need to have a non-null "surrogate delete value" and let the aggregation function return `null` if it sees this "surrogate delete value".

Answer (score 0):

#2 and #4 are not stores - they are internal topics created by Kafka Streams.

There is no way to explicitly cleanup these repartition topics but Kafka would automatically cleanup these based on the kafka server's `retention.ms` config (which is default of 7 days if not specified explicitly) as these topics (#2 and #4) are created by Kafka Streams with `cleanup.policy = delete`.

Comment: This answer only applies to older Kafka Streams versions. In newer version, the retention time is set to "infinity" and Kafka Streams uses explicit "delete request" to truncate repartition topics after record were successfully processed downstream.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax just to make sure I understand correctly - when the next processor in the topology "acks" a record has been processed successfully (when it was sent to the next processor?) Kafka streams automatically sends a tombstone to the repartition topic?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax, furthermore - are these "explicit delete requests" implemented with tombstones? I looked at some repartition topics and could not find any tombstones (thought it does seem like records are deleted from these topic, as the oldest offsets are from the last couple of minutes)

Comment: There are no tombstones involved -- and it's base on a sub-topology granularity (not per processor). After a record is consumed and fully processed by all processors in the sub-topology and all result records are flushed, the corresponding offsets are committed and in addition a "purge record" API call is made (it's basically a "truncate at offset" request using the committed offset as cut-off point). -- "truncate at offset" is not a hard cut-off point as the current active segment cannot be truncated, so the actual truncation "lags" a little bit behind committed offsets.